# How to use the AND operator?

Tags: c#, regex

How to match multiple strings from sentence using Regex in C#?
For example in the below sentence I want to check if the strings `L - V` and `Dom` exists or not.

> L - V 8:30 a 22:00 hrs. Sab y Dom..11:00 a 22:00 hrs.

I am having issue with AND operator in Regex.

```
Regex.IsMatch(hours, @"\bL - V\b.*?\Dom\b")
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: show us the code that you're using

Comment: Your code returns true. What's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can either do it as a single regex such as `/L - V.*Dom/` or do two matches and an and.

Answer (score 2):

It might be more clear to use two separate regexes (or just [the `String.indexOf(String)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904283)) and C#'s regular `&&` operator; but if you want to put it into a single regex, then you can write either of these:

```
L - V.*Dom                <-- if `L - V` will always come before `Dom`
(L - V.*Dom|Dom.*L - V)   <-- if you don't know which will come first
```

(`.` means "any character other than newline", so `.*` means "zero or more non-newline characters", i.e. "any substring that doesn't contain newlines").

Answer (score 2):

It can be done simply as

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string txt="L - V 8:30 a 22:00 hrs. Sab y Dom..11:00 a 22:00 hrs.";

      string re1="(L)"; // Any Single Character 1
      string re2=".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
      string re3="(-)"; // Any Single Character 2
      string re4=".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
      string re5="(V)"; // Any Single Character 3
      string re6=".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
      string re7="(Dom)";   // Word 1

      Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
      Match m = r.Match(txt);
      if (m.Success)
      {
            String c1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
            String c2=m.Groups[2].ToString();
            String c3=m.Groups[3].ToString();
            String word1=m.Groups[4].ToString();
            Console.Write("("+c1.ToString()+")"+"("+c2.ToString()+")"+"("+c3.ToString()+")"+"("+word1.ToString()+")"+"\n");
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I prefer to use Regex as I've many different conditions. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Regex try with:

```
bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(hours, @"^\bL - V\b.*?\Dom.*$");
```

but you can also say

```
bool isMatch = hours.IndexOf("L - V") != -1 && hours.IndexOf("Dom") != -1
```

maybe without regex is even simpler, in my opinion if something can be done without regex, do it without regex. Maybe in this case if you want to be more tolerant, for instance match even `L-V` or `L-    V` it worths to use regex ( but we need to modify the expression ).

Answer (score 2):

It is the default behavoir of RegEx to combine the terms with AND. Your expression is almost correct, except for the backslash before the "D" of "Dom". You could also append a "\b" before "Dom"  in order to find only whole words. Also the "?" makes no difference if you only want to check for the existence of the pattern.

```
\bL - V\b.*\bDom\b
```

If the string should contain either "L - V" or "Dom", the Expression would be

```
\b(L - V|Dom)\b
```

If finding whole words is not important, you can drop alle the "\b"s in both expressions
   (`"L - V.*Dom"` resp. `"L - V|Dom"`) or just do it with

```
hours.Contains("L - V") && hours.Contains("Dom")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your regex returns true, so I'm not sure why you're having problems. Having said that, a regex seems like a possible overkill here, especially if you don't know which string comes first. I might just do this:

```
var haystack = "L - V 8:30 a 22:00 hrs. Sab y Dom..11:00 a 22:00 hrs.";
if (new List<string> { "L - V", "Dom" }.TrueForAll(needle => haystack.Contains(needle))) 
{
  ///stuff
}
```